# Calculate: $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^{\sqrt{(\ln n)^2 + \ln n^2}}}{n^2+1}$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{10^{\sqrt{(\ln n)^2 + \ln n^2}}}{n^2+1}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

I have to evaluate the following limits (which are similar). However, I don't know how to evaluate them. Could you give me a hand?

> > $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^{\sqrt{(\ln n)^2 + \ln n^2}}}{n^2+1}$$
> >     $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{10^{\sqrt{(\ln n)^2 + \ln n^2}}}{n^2+1}$$

---

As a sidenote, according to the solutions given in my book, the first one is $0$ and the second one is $+\infty$ which seems very strange to me: it is surely a typo.

Comment: If one is finite, the other should be finite as well, right?

Comment: The way you wrote it those answers you gave are impossible.

Comment: @avid19 I know. This makes me even more troubled, because I don't know how to evaluate them.

Comment: The question is wrong, or you wrote it here wrong.

Comment: @grdgfgr The question is to evaluate the limit! (The answers provided by the book may be wrong)

Comment: OH, now I look at the answer and it makes sense. It is difficult to notice that the square root is in the exponent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(\ln(n))^2 + \ln(n^2) \sim (\ln(n))^2$$

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^{\sqrt{(\ln n)^2 + \ln n^2}}}{n^2+1} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^{\sqrt{(\ln n)^2}}}{n^2+1} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^{\ln(n)}}{n^2+1} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^{\ln(2)}}{n^2+1}$$

Similarly for the other one.

Note that as $2 > \ln(2)$, that goes to $0$. As $\ln(10) > 2$, the other goes to $\infty$.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on the very first step.

Comment: @user62029, $\sim$ means that the ratio of the first to the second goes to $\infty$, which makes the first the dominant term near $\infty$.

Comment: Also, why the very last step is that way?

Comment: $\ln(n^2)$ in the square root is not negligible. If the limit were finite, you would get a wrong answer.

Comment: Give an example @grdgfgr.

Comment: $$\lim_{n\to \infty } \, \frac{\left(e^2\right)^{\sqrt{\log ^2(n)+2 \log (n)}}}{n^2+1}=e^2$$ but $$\lim_{n\to \infty } \, \frac{\left(e^2\right)^{\sqrt{\log ^2(n)}}}{n^2+1}=1$$

Comment: @user62029 what is the problem with the last step?

Comment: Why is $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^{\ln(n)}}{n^2+1} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^{\ln(2)}}{n^2+1}$?

Comment: @user62029 It is a logarithm identity. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logarithmic_identities#Using_simpler_operations fifth one

Comment: @user62029 because $2^{\ln(n)} = e^{\ln(2^{\ln(n)})} = e^{\ln(n) \ln(2)} = (e^{ln(n)})^{\ln(2)} = n^{\ln(2)}$

Comment: @grdgfgr: would you please explain how you got the first limit?

Comment: can you understand the second one? because in the first one you have $$\sqrt{(\ln(n))^2+2\ln(n)+1}=\ln(n)+1$$ in the exponent, which then turns into first limit times $e^2$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** $\ln(n)<\sqrt{(\ln(n))^2+2\ln(n)}<\sqrt{(\ln(n))^2+2\ln(n)+1}=\ln(n)+1$